# How to start two independent incognito Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

If I open two incognito windows (Ctrl+Shift+N) and sign in service in one of them, I singed in other (the same cookie, I guess). How to do independent this two windows?

Answer (score 14):

Incognito Mode Windows are limited to one per Chrome profile. To get more than one (without installing another instance of Chrome), you could add a new Chrome profile. More details [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en).

Comment: Can I run profiles simultaneously?

Comment: @Suncatcher - yes, you can open up many Chrome profiles and each one would have its own Incognito Mode window. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824

Comment: Last time I switched between profiles they were replacing each other in current Chrome window, maybe things have changed since then. Will try again.

Answer (score 13):

What you are looking for is **SessionBox** ([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig)). It is the analogous of Multi-Account Containers for Firefox.

Each Box/Container stores cookies separately, so you can log into the same site with different accounts and online trackers can’t easily connect the browsing, i.e. for every browser window or tab you can log in to the same site with a different account.

You can customize tab's labels and colors to help keep your different activities or accounts separate.

Comment: that one is awesome!

Comment: though not really an incognito window

Comment: is it really important?

Comment: if you consider not leaving traces in browser history it can be important yes

Comment: This is for the moment my best alternative. Very good extension, even a bit difficult to manage in the beginning.

Comment: only free for non-commercial use with max 5 simultaneous sessions! Maybe MultiLogin extension is another alternative - but somebody posted this to be spyware (?) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24690#c133

Answer (score 8):

Option 1: Use another, independant running instance of chrome, eg: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Option 2: Setup another user profile and limit how long cookies etc are stored: [image]

Comment: How independent? That link appears only to be good for Microsoft Windows users. Is it good enough to run chrome again from a terminal, say? Or perhaps on GNU/Linux I could use cgroups to make sure the chromium server application can't communicate to the other incognito session's browser tab processes?

Comment: It's very cumbersome to create new profile each time you gonna create new incognito session. No other way? No automated way?

Answer (score 3):

**`--temp-profile`**

On Ubuntu 18.04 Chromium 80, using temporary profiles instead of incognito windows worked:

```
nohup chromium-browser --temp-profile > /dev/null 2>&1
nohup chromium-browser --temp-profile > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If I login on Stack Overflow in the first instance, I still need to login into the second one.

As far as I can see, no data carries over from my main Chromium session into those, for example passwords are not remembered by the browser either.

Interestingly, also giving the `--incognito` option with `--temp-profile` appears to disable the `--temp-profile`, and logins are shared, which is unexpected.

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/304293/how-to-start-fresh-chromium-instance

Comment: Does this work on Windows? I tried `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --temp-profile C:\Windows\Temp` and it opened another Chrome window with mine profile, maybe I'm doing smth wrong?

Comment: @Suncatcher I don't know about Windows, let me know if you find something else. You don't need to pass `C:\Windows\Temp `.

Comment: On my side I also tried this using Ubuntu WSL + Chrome.exe but temp-profile's seems also to be shared (not working). On Windows + Chrome, I went with the `SessionBox` extension which is working fine.

Comment: From what I can see when using the option "--temp-profile" under Linux, it creates a random temporary directory in "/tmp".  Something like "/tmp/tmp.dm4qSGkKBf".  Not sure about Windows.

To be certain that Chrome/Chromium doesn't use your profile, try adding "--user-data-dir=/tmp/(somerandomname)" or "--user-data-dir=C:\Windows\Temp\(somerandomname)" to the command line as well.  This will create the profile in that temporary directory.  It can, maybe should, be used with the "--temp-profile" option and "--incognito" option.  There's a slight difference using "--temp-profile" and not.